# Upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 boot problem

Tags: boot, upgrade, xserver

I’ve used Ubuntu for 3 months now so I’m quite new to Linux or UNIX systems.  And would love any help anyone can give me on this problem.

I recently upgraded my machine from 11.10 to 12.04.
At first my grub was weird (dual boot), now I’m able to get into windows.
However, when I select Ubuntu 12.04, it would briefly show the startup screen then it just goes to tty1 and prompting me for username and password.  After I enter my username and password I can use the system fine in terminal.  How can I get back the desktop?  Let Ubuntu work properly?

After I get to tty1, there are three lines of error that keep repeating, they are as followed.

```
[  799.17958] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
[  799.23426] ieee80211 phy0: brcmsmac: wl_ops_bss_info_change: disassociated
[  799.36745] ieee80211 phy0:wl_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled false, count 1 (implement)
```

The numbers in front would keep on changing.

After I typed startx the whole screen goes blank....I'm looking at the log file....I don't know what to look for it's vary long maybe I try to upload this file somewhere so that you can have a look???

My Xorg.0.log file is here pastebin.com/t22Svw4U

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with your xserver.

Try this

```
dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

to reconfigure your xserver configuration

According to your Xorg.log it could also be a driver problem with your ATI graphic card. Do you have the newest version installed?
There was a post before. Perhaps this helps:

[What is the correct way to install ATI Catalyst Video Drivers in 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-in-12-04-lts)

Comment: Thanks for the reply I tried it and I rebooted...it's still the same...any other suggestions?

Comment: Try to type startx just to see if your xserver starts. If you get graphical interface then it's a problem with your display manager

Comment: Have a look in your xserver log file for any error messages. Log file can be found in /var/log/Xorg.0.log

Comment: After I typed startx the whole screen goes blank....I'm looking at the log file....I don't know what to look for it's vary long maybe I try to upload this file somewhere so that you can have a look???

Comment: put it on pastebin and post the url here

Comment: Oh..okay I think I found one error (EE):
(EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory

Comment: http://pastebin.com/t22Svw4U
Here is the file, thanks.

Comment: @Mike Please put all this information in your question, not buried in the comments!

Comment: use the edit button below your question

Comment: Yes it worked all I did was 
    sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh  
Thank you so much !!!